# Three20 openURLAction - How to reverse the transition effect?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

E.g.

```
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:url] applyAnimated:YES]];
```

The default transition is move the new controller from **Right** to the **Left**

I want the reverse, exactly the transition when you back the parent controller by pressing the nav. controller left buttom - move the new controller from **Left** to the **Right**.

Any easy way to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please view [Better NavigationController transition in Three20 using TTURLAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226340/better-navigationcontroller-transition-in-three20-using-tturlaction) on how to create a custom animation when navigating between controllers.

I guess your transition type will by `kCATransitionPush` and the subtype `kCATransitionFromLeft`. See [CATransition Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)